# The fastest way to find indices of element in the 2D python list

Tags: python, list, numpy, indices

I have a problem with the efficient implementation of searching indices of elements in 2D list.
For example, there are two lists (where list2 have permuted elements from list1):

```
list1 = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]

list2 = [[8,2],[1,9],[6,4],[13,5,0],[14,7,10],[12,11,3]]
```

In the end, I would like to have list3, which is the same size and shape as two mentioned lists. I need list3 to look like this, in this example:

```
list3 = [[3,1],[0,5],[2,3],[2,4,0],[1,4,5],[5,3,4]]
```

so the first element '3' is the index of sublist in list2, in which sublist is the element '0' from the list1. I hope that it is clear. Main problem is based on the search of the element from list1 in list2. For bigger lists of size 100 000, it is really hard.

I have tried this code, which contains 4 'for loops' and another one which is based of np.argwhere, but numpy implementation is even more time consuming.

**1st implementation**

```
for index1, sublist1 in enumerate(list1):
    for i in range(len(sublist1)):

        for index2, sublist2 in enumerate(list2):
            for j in range(len(sublist2)):
                if sublist2[j] == sublist[1]:
                    list1[index1][i] = index1
                    list2[index2][j] = index2
```

**2nd implementation**

```
for index1, sublist1 in enumerate(list1):
    for i in range(len(sublist1)):
        where = np.argwhere(list2 == sublist1[i])
        list1[index1][i] = where[0, 0]
```

I hope that there can be another implementation which is a lot faster than these two, especially for lists of bigger size, i.e. 100 000.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary mapping from the `list2` and use it afterwards to create your output:

```py
list1 = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
list2 = [[8, 2], [1, 9], [6, 4], [13, 5, 0], [14, 7, 10], [12, 11, 3]]

m = {v: i for i, t in enumerate(list2) for v in t}
out = [[m[list1[i][j]] for j in range(len(t))] for i, t in enumerate(list2)]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[3, 1], [0, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4, 0], [1, 4, 5], [5, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Why don't just just iterate over the lists of list1? (and sorry for the simultaneous posting!) ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah, I was overthinking it. Iterating over `list1` is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a mapping dictionary for the indices of the sublists in `list2`, then a list comprehension:

```
mapper = {x: i for i, l in enumerate(list2) for x in l}

list3 = [[mapper.get(x, -1) for x in l] for l in list1]
```

*NB. I assigned `-1` to the potentially missing values. Also if you have duplicates in `list2` the last index will be used.*

Output: `[[3, 1], [0, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4, 0], [1, 4, 5], [5, 3, 4]]`

Answer (score 0):

convert `list2` to dict, where key is each element in sublist and value is index of the said sublist. You will need extra care if there are duplicates - how you want to treat them is unclear right now. Then iterate over `list1` to create the expected output.

```
list1 = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
list2 = [[8,2],[1,9],[6,4],[13,5,0],[14,7,10],[12,11,3]]

lookup_dict = {key:idx for idx, sublist in enumerate(list2) for key in sublist}
result = [[lookup_dict.get(key) for key in item] for item in list1]
print(result)
```

output

```
[[3, 1], [0, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4, 0], [1, 4, 5], [5, 3, 4]]
```